# searching custom node type contents from a module

Tags: 7, search

If I create my own custom node type by writing my own module(s), is Drupal "smart" enough to index the contents of this new node type from my module?  If not, then would I need to use the Search API's so that contents are included in search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core search module will index all nodes, no matter where they have been defined (manually through admin/custom module.).

Comment: Thanks.  I will just have to take your word for it.  I was hoping more people would chime in to confirm what you said.

Comment: You're welcome. You can test that easily - enable search, create content type, index it and then try to find it on the front end.